# why we associate matrix pencil $A-\lambda E$ to Differential Algebraic Equation $E\dot x=Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone tell me the reason why we study matrix pencil $A-\lambda E$ to study the solution space of  Differential Algebraic Equation $E\dot x(t)=Ax(t)$ where $E,A$ are $n\times n$ real singular  matrices but $\det (A-\lambda E)\ne 0$  and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ complex variable.

are we making any similarity betwen $\lambda$ and the operator $d\over dt$?

$(A-E{d\over dt})x(t)=0=(A-\lambda E)x(t)$, something like this?

Comment: Are you comfortable with this kind of analysis in the case that $E$ is the identity matrix (i.e. the standard linear ODE)?

Comment: **Note:** Solving $\det(A - \lambda E) \neq 0$ is called the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem).

Comment: well I have to study solution space of this particular type of DAE, for $E=I$ I haven't study anything. oh I have studied one paper : on the eigen value problem $\lambda Tx+Sx$

Comment: I know about generalized eigen value problem but whats the connection between these two?

Comment: $\det(A - \lambda E) = 0$ if and only if there is a non-zero vector $x$ such that $(A - \lambda E)x = 0$

Comment: and this particular question came to my mind while reading this paper https://www.tu-ilmenau.de/fileadmin/media/math/Preprints/2009/09_21_berger.pdf

Comment: Yes but my question is are we making any connection between $\lambda$ and $d\over dt$?

Comment: No, that's not usually the way that the connection is explained.  The direct connection is that if $Ax_0 = \lambda Ex_0$, then the equation $E \dot x = Ax$ with initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ has a nice solution, and (usually) we can put the solutions like these together to get a full answer.

Comment: Is there a valid way to interpret substituting $\frac d{dt}$ with $\lambda$?  Perhaps, but not one that I know of.  This problem is significantly easier to understand in the case of $E = I$, and that problem is usually covered in an undergraduate class on ordinary differential equations, so I'm surprised that you haven't at least seen it.  I think it's possible to interpret the substitution nicely in those circumstances, but I don't know if that interpretation can be generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main connection is that any $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ is an Eigenvalue of the differential operator since $\frac{d}{dt} e^{\lambda t} = \lambda e^{\lambda t}$, hence if $\det (A-\lambda E) = 0$ then there is a vector $x_0$ such that $Ax_0 = \lambda E x_0$ which immediately gives rise to the 'trivial' solution $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}x_0$.

So this case is not really interesting since the DAE essentially becomes the ODE $\dot x  = \lambda x$ for $x\in\ker(A-\lambda E)$.

However you should not confuse this with the definition of a **regular** DAE, which is that $\det(A-Es) \neq 0 $ as a **polynomial** in $\mathbb K[s]$.

As it turns out regular DAEs can be decomposed into 2 parts: an ODE part as described above, and a NDAE part (E nilpotent). Regular DAEs admit existence and uniqueness of solutions, given that the initial condition is compatible with the NDAE.